# Complete gradient shrinking Ricci solitons not having non-negative curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Are there examples of complete gradient shrinking Ricci solitons not having non-negative Ricci curvature?

Comment: Look up Feldman Llmanen Knopf. They construct shrinking Kahler solitons which do not have non-negative Ricci curvature. It is interesting to know also that, Maximo proved these arise as blowup limits of closed Ricci flows.

Comment: @OtisChodosh, I can not find the this paper(s), can you make the ref more precise?

Answer (score 5):

My comment seemed to get jumbled, so here is an expanded version:

In 3-d, an ancient complete Ricci flow (so, in particular a shrinking soliton) will have non-negative sectional curvature. This follows from a result of Chen, http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3081.pdf, Corollary 2.4. (If the manifold has controlled geometry at infinity, this follows from earlier results like Hamilton-Ivey pinching).

However, in higher dimensions, Hamilton-Ivey style pinching estimates do not work. (*). Indeed, as your question asks, there *are* shrinkers with non-positive Ricci curvature. For example, the solitons constructed by Feldman-Ilmanen-Knopf in http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1090511686 do not have non-negative Ricci curvature.

An interesting question is whether or not these can arise as singularity models for a compact Ricci flow, and this was answered in the affirmative by Maximo: http://math.stanford.edu/~maximo/Maximo%20-%20On%20the%20blow-up%20of%20four%20dimensional%20Ricci%20flow%20singularities.pdf. An interesting consequence of his work is that positive Ricci curvature is not preserved along the flow in higher dimensions (EDIT: as remarked the answer by @BewSMA, the lack of preservation of Ricci curvature under the flow was already observed).

---

EDIT: I'll just point out that the above paper of Chen proves that a shrinker must have non-negative *scalar* curvature (see Corollary 2.5).

---

(*) In spite of this aspect of the theory failing, there are curvature conditions which are preserved under the flow. For example, see http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-01/S0894-0347-08-00613-9/S0894-0347-08-00613-9.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For the positive Ricci curvature not preserved by Ricci flow, the first compact example(as I know) is given by Boehm and Wilking in the following paper(the example is 12 dimensional with positive sectional curvature initially):

Nonnegatively curved manifolds with finite fundamental groups admit metrics with positive Ricci curvature. Geom. Funct. Anal. 17 (2007), no. 3, 665–681.

Complete examples that the non-negative sectional curvature is not preserved by Ricci flow are given by Lei Ni in the following paper:

Ricci flow and nonnegativity of sectional curvature, Math. Res. Lett. 11(2004), 883-904.

Ni's construction is quite interesting that uses Cheeger-Gromoll splitting. One may check if the non-negative Ricci curvature on his example is preserved or not.

Comment: For the preserved conditions by Ricci flow, Wilking gave a unified approach for known conditions:

A Lie algebraic approach to Ricci flow invariant curvature conditions and Harnack inequalities. J. Reine Angew. Math. 679 (2013), 223–247.

Comment: These are all very interesting examples, but this does not seem to answer the original question, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Your answer is absolutely fine. I just add some comments to your answer, not to the original problem.

Comment: Great! Nice comments, I didn't know about some of these exampkes, thanks!